# how to setup secure access to a host on internet?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, internet

we are planning to setup a source code repo + bug tracker for multiple users across the globe. Hence the network is internet - that is the host has public IP address provided by the ISP.

since this host is not a registered domain or IP on the internet, how can the problem of access from internet to this host be solved?

what software , hardware is required

Comment: If the ISP can provide you with an IP, why not get a domain name to use for this, the cost is minimal.

Comment: Indeed, and while your at it, get an SSL for the secure part.

Comment: I always feel that if you need to ask the question you really shouldn't be doing this yourself. Get someone who knows what they're doing and fully understands the risks and consequences to do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a virtual server with [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com) instance or a VPS provider. With Amazon you get free static IP and then you either access it by IP address or register a domain name. For security, if it is linux then IPtables is the key word. Alternatively and if you go with amazon, you are also getting free virtual firewall that is more then adequate. And for connectivity make sure you use encrypted connections (ssl, ssh) and you will be fine. If you concerned about DOS attacks the talk to professional - there is no easy solution for this. Hope this helps.

Comment: can I setup this virtual server on my own? please eloborate

Comment: Just create account with amazon, then login to the console and create your server. They only charge you if server is running and you can start from as low as few cents per hour and then grow as you need. You will have a few choices for operating systems - Windows, CentOS, Ubuntu and probably SUSE.

Comment: BTW, Amazon is just one example. Another option that comes to mind is [rackspace cloud](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/) or you can even go with VPS from almost every web-hosting provider (GoDaddy for example).

Answer (score 1):

When you plan this setup i think its better you take a server from an internet hoster. Then you get an ip and domain and webspace.

When you want to put the server in your local intranet then you need to forward the port to your server. But then you have opened your system for people from outside and you need an external ip-adress. If you don't get one you can use something like "[dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/)" but i think its not the best way.